# Can I create a new version of a phonegap app and publish it as an update when I only have the html?

Tags: ios, cordova

So this one client wants to publish a new version of their iOS phonegap app, problem is, they only have the html, since that's all that the previous developer left them.

I am not using phonegap build, I would be using the phonegap cli, and the previous developer used the cli too, as far as I now.

Thanks.

Comment: If the developer did not leave them with passwords and keys, then you cannot publish a new version. Request the developer's contact info and get in touch with him/her and explain what you need.

Comment: That's kind of a dead end, things did not end well I'm afraid. They do have access to the developer account, the keys can be downloaded from there as far as I know. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Have you tried making a PG app out of the HTML you have on hand? If so, at what step does it fail?

Comment: I would now know yet, they haven't provided me with all of the info, I expect they do tomorrow, but the requirement is explicit enough for the question to arise, they don't have access to the previous developer's mac, they only have access to the developer account since its theirs and they need to publish an update. I will get back to you as soon as i get all of the info/files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that when you say the html you mean all the web content that was used to build the app, i.e. javascript, CSS, images etc. In that case you can rebuild the app as a new Phonegap app but you will need more than access to the developer's account as you also need the private keys used to create the signing identity.

You may need to recreate a new signing identity which is simple enough to do but will make the app a new app and not an upgrade.

Comment: Supposedly, my client needs to deploy as an update, I'll try some of the suggestions I've got so far and will most definately let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can if you can download the code signing. From Apple:

> To sign apps, you must have both the signing identity and the
>   intermediate certificate installed in your keychain. When you install
>   Xcode, Apple’s intermediate certificates are added to your keychain
>   for you. You use Xcode to create your signing identity and sign your
>   app. Your signing identity is added to your keychain and the
>   corresponding certificate is added to your account in Member Center.
>
> Signing identities are used to sign your app or installer package. A
>   development certificate identifies you, as a team member, in a
>   development provisioning profile that allows apps signed by you to
>   launch on devices. A distribution certificate identifies your team or
>   organization in a distribution provisioning profile and allows you to
>   submit your app to the store. Only a team agent or an admin can create
>   a distribution certificate. You also use different development and
>   distribution certificates to sign iOS and Mac apps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW1

Comment: I believe I won't be able to get the intermediate certificae, I will get back to you if I do, thanks!